# Window is java program drawn off screen

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, ubuntu

Ever since my power went out mid project this program has been drawing my window off screen and I can't figure out why. Whenever it launches I can't move the window into a useful position, but when I alt-tab to see all the programs running on my computer I can see my jpanel. If it matters I am on Ubuntu using Eclipse.
EDIT: I tested this with a totally different java program I didn't make and it does the same thing, so it appears to be an issue with my IDE/OS

I removed my code because it doesn't appear to have anything to do with the problem.

Comment: Formatting improved for your QuizGame. In the future, please don't strive to make it hard for others to read your code. Rather, you'll likely get better and quicker answers if you do the exact opposite: make it as easy as possible to read your posted code.

Comment: Don't set your GUI visible **before** adding components to it. Instead add components to your JPanel and add the JPanel to your JFrame, and only then set the JFrame visible after packing it.

Comment: `"I tested this with a totally different program and it does the same thing, so it appears to be an issue with my IDE/OS"` -- unless your other program has bad code in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is a problem with your code, rather a slip up in the Ubuntu OS when they tried to make something more ergonomic. You might want to try running the program on a virtual machine or on another computer to see where the window is spawned on there. Usually when you move around a window on your screen and then close it, when the same program gets re-opened it will open in the same place it was closed at. This might even happen with all java applications for you now unless you move it and close it somewhere in the middle of your screen. You might be able to fix it by changing your resolution and trying to grab a corner of the screen but I'm not sure.

EDIT: Alt + F7 is a shortcut on ubuntu to move your current window. Move yours to the center of your screen and close it and you might be good.

EDIT: This is not mine but this script can be found here: https://github.com/mezga0153/offscreen-window-restore/blob/master/offscreen-window-restore.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# This script moves back windows that have been moved off screen
#
# Author: Tine Mezgec tine.mezgec@gmail.com
#

width=`xrandr | grep current | awk {'print $8'}`

`wmctrl -l -G | awk -v w=$width '{
    if ($8 != "unity-dash" && $8 != "Hud") {
        if ($3 >= w || $3 < 0) {
            system("wmctrl -i -r " $1 " -e 0," sqrt($3*$3) % w ",-1,-1,-1");
        }
    }
}'`
```

This is all I could find, beware all your windows might open in the same place when the script is running though. You also might want to try moving the window with the arrow keys, closing and re-opening it then.

Comment: Alt+f7 does move it into view, but when I close it in place and close the program it still appears off screen.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I think the problem has something to do with having more than one monitor.

To fix this I went into my system settings, then disabled one of my monitors in the display menu.

Then, I launched my program and then closed it.

Finally I re-enabled my other monitor and everything works fine now.